# Force React to reload an image file?

Tags: reactjs

My React app allows users to upload profile images. This is done by uploading the image to an Amazon S3 bucket and storing the path to the image in my database, along with the date and time the image was uploaded. The filename of the image is set to the user's ID.

Im having a problem when a user uploads a new image. As the image path is the same React doesn't know anything has changed, meaning I have to refresh the page to see the change.

As I have a date field I can use componentWillReceiveProps to know when a new image has been uploaded. The following console.log does fire at the correct time:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (this.state.picDate.getTime() !== nextProps.user.pic.date.getTime()) {
        console.log('image date has changed');
        // this.forceUpdate();
    }
}
```

Can I use this to re-render the image? I tried `this.forceUpdate()` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

I think that's because of the browser cache. try adding some hash like `date.now()` after image URL changes. for example:

```
setState({
   imageSrc: '...',
   imageHash: Date.now()
})
```

and in render:

```
render(){
  return(
      <img src={`${imageSrc}?${imageHash}`} />
  )
}
```

Comment: Why doesn't it work to render the `img` with a new `key`? I thought that would recreate the dom element? (It's not the cache - no request show up at all in the network dev tools tab)

Comment: Good advice, I was tricked into this same mistake. In fact my state was OK but the cache was not updating my image source. Thanks.

Comment: @olejorgenb Same question here. Actually, the way of updating the key of <img> came to my mind at first, but the <img> wasn't updated.

Comment: I guess it's not about the DOM, it's all about the browser assets cach

Comment: This was great to know about. Since I am fetching the url from a DB, any updated just adds a hash now and I don't need to do it on the frontend now.

Comment: @olejorgenb Updating the key just re-renders the DOM but the browser still uses the same source ref as long as it has the same src URL where is browser cache

Answer (score 20):

I was having this issue with a local image. The image was being modified, but the URL was staying the same.

The trick was just to add a key property to the image that changed whenever the image changed. For instance:

```
<Image key={Date.now()} source={{uri: <your local uri>}/>
```

[Source: this GitHub comment](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9195#issuecomment-238190537)

Comment: I find this to be cleaner than the accepted solution. In my case, I can't change the `img` src attribute because it's a remote URL.

Comment: Instead of Date.now() you can also use something like this: Math.random().toString(36). You can also control moment of reload using the key value based on state variable.

Comment: This solution doesn't account for browser / proxy caching

Comment: This solution with `key` is **super clever** and works for vanilla React too!

Comment: Worked great but if you are rendering multiple components with a map function, keys are going to duplicate. I recommend adding the index of that recursion to force them to be different. e.g.
``` {arr.map((properties, index) => <ComponentName key={Date.now() + index} />}```

Answer (score 7):

Its working fine for me.

```
<img src={`${props.src}?${new Date().getTime()}`} />
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try doing something like first set state to null so image wont display and again set state to particular image with path.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
         image_path : 'before update image path'
    };
}    

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (this.state.picDate.getTime() !== nextProps.user.pic.date.getTime()) {
        console.log('image date has changed');
        //now here set state
        this.setState({
          image_path : 'your new image path or older as you explained both are same' + '?' + Math.random()
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

(Enhancement to Eric Wiener answer), set key (ie. timestamp) upon upload to s3 to get a cleaner refresh.

```
const [timestamp, setTimestamp] = React.useState(Date.now());

axios.post("/api/upload/s3", formData)
    .then(res => {
        setTimestamp(Date.now())
    })

<Avatar key={timestamp} className={classes.avatar} src={user_info.avatar} onClick={handleOpenPicture}></Avatar>
```

Answer (score 2):

Better solution may be to change the structure of your code and API

**Solution 1**
Add a updatedDate to the object and use that. It needs to be a full Date value.

```js
const bypassCache = new Date(updatedDate).getTime()
const imageUrl = `${image.url}?${bypassCache}`

// imageUrl = https://example.com/userId/imageId?16504372055
```

You'd need a value that's unique for the new entry compared to the previous. If you need to compare, you may use useRef to hold the initial value and then compare to the new updatedDate.

**Solution 2**
Store the bypassCache in the pathname itself `https://example.com/userId/imageId/bypassCache`

Thereby handling it from "backend". For the users privacy you may use a different unique value that cannot be parsed/reversed into a real timestamp.

Answer (score 2):

The solution working for me is to add a bypassCache like this:

```js
image.src = url + "?" + Math.random().toString(36);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set image path blank and then set to whatever your path was, react will assume its a change and new pic will be loaded.

```
this.setState({image_path : ''});               
this.setState({image_path : 'Actual Image Source'});
```

Like I am doing in my `FileUpload` function

```
this.setState({userimage:''});  
this.setState({userimage:"http://localhost:5000/auth/getProfilePic/" + this.state.username,});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add current date as query parameter to the image url

```
<img src={`${image_url}?${global.Date.now()}`} />
```

Comment: welcome. Thanks for joining stackoverflow. Just a small recommendation would be to explain why and how this solution works also is very similar to the accepted answer so make sure to propuse new value even if its by being more specific in the why :)

Answer (score 0):

This works on functional components (I haven't tried it on class based components but it should work too):

```js
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [source, setSource] = useState('some_image.png');

  const changeImage = (newSource) => {
    setSource(null);
    setTimeout(() => setSource(newSource));
  };

  return (
    <img 
      src={source}
    />
  );
};
```

Note: **I have tried using random hash and also changing key, they didn't work. This might work for you**

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was changing the image name with every new upload, for example:

```
const new_file_name = Date.now() . '/' . file_extension
```

This new file name needs to be stored on some database, relating it to the user. It's also a good idea that each user has a folder, to avoid that two users have the same image name.

When loading the app, request the user image name from the api and you will get the name of the file. As you know the user, you know in which folder to search for this.

In case you are uploading the file and want to see the image change immediately, store this file name into a react or redux state. The Image element will re-render on change.

To get the image from your api do something like:

```
<Image
  source={{ 
    uri: your_localhost_ip + ':' + your_port +'/'+ your_folder_containing_all_user_pics + '/' + user_id + '/' + user_picture,
    cache:'reload' //only works for ios
  }}
/>
```