# React img not immediately changing when src changes. How can I fix this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a basic `<img>` with a src.

```
<img src={src} />
```

If I change the src from say `/1.jpg` to `/2.jpg` and the new image takes 1 second to load, React will continue to show `/1.jpg` until the new image is loaded.

What I want is for the old image to be discarded while the new image is being loaded. (e.g. display: none)

Any idea how to accomplish this? Ideally without conditional rendering, because I still need to use `onLoad` and `onError`

EDIT: Here's some more code. It's a little more complicated than my question, but I'm just trying to add some loading and error state to the image.

I have a button that calls this onClick

```
this.props.history.push('/${page + 1}');
```

This is the image component, where src is based on the `page` from the URL.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import CenteredLoading from 'components/loading/CenteredLoading';

type Props = { src: string };

type State = {
  status: 'LOADING' | 'LOADED' | 'FAILED',
};

class ImageWithLoader extends Component<Props, State> {
  state = {
    status: 'LOADING',
  };

  handleImageLoad = () => {
    this.setState({ status: 'LOADED' });
    console.error('image loaded');
  };

  handleImageError = () => {
    this.setState({ status: 'FAILED' });
    console.error('image error');
  };

  render() {
    const { src, ...otherProps } = this.props;
    const { status } = this.state;

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <img
        {...otherProps}
        onLoad={this.handleImageLoad}
        onError={this.handleImageError}
        src={src}
        />

        {status === 'LOADING' && <CenteredLoading />}
        {status === 'FAILED' && <p>error</p>}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default ImageWithLoader;
```

Comment: Code? You can change that by updating the state.

Comment: For a more modern (and working) answer check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68229586/6266412

Comment: @Imran , can you look at my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72482129/react-js-how-to-update-image-only-once-loaded/72482353

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Made my own workaround.

I believe because react isn't mounting a new component (i.e. `<img>`), it's not going to update to the new image until it's finished loading.

What I did was check if the `src` changed in `componentDidUpdate` and change the status to `LOADING`. Then I set img style to `display: none` while its status was `LOADING`.

EDIT: Also, by manually setting my own key, I can force React to re-render the `<img>`

Answer (score 44):

Just add key attribute to your image tag and assign some unique value to key attribute like image source.

```html
<img src={image_source} key={image_source}></img>
```

Comment: It's the exact same code as you proposed.

Comment: then it should work. May be your src is not changing.Share some code of how you are changing your src and adding it into the dom.

Comment: I actually found out, that the url itself does not change. But the image changes in the cloud. So I think this is a different problem.

Comment: @AG_HIHI Thanks for commenting that - just realized that's the problem I am having