# React JS - How to update image only once loaded?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a React app that receives a stream of image URIs from an `EventSource`. I want to display the most recent image, and only replace the image once the next image is fully loaded and can be displayed instantaneously. How do I accomplish this?

Edit 2: My current implementation does exactly this, except for one critical component: the most recent image is displayed as it loads, changing the vertical arrangement of the page.

Edit: Adding relevant snippets of code, this is my `EventSource`:

```
  useEffect(() => {

    let serverImageURIsEventSource = new EventSource(
      url,
      {withCredentials: false})

    serverImageURIsEventSource.addEventListener('open', () => {
      console.log('SSE opened!');
    });

    serverImageURIsEventSource.addEventListener('message', (e) => {
      console.log(e.data);
      setImageURIs([e.data]);  // e.data is a string to the image URI
    });

    serverImageURIsEventSource.addEventListener('error', (e) => {
      console.error('Error: ',  e);
    });

    serverImageURIsEventSource.addEventListener('close', () => {
      console.log('SSE closed!');
      serverImageURIsEventSource.close();
    });

    return () => {
      serverImageURIsEventSource.close();
    };
  }, [prompt]);
```

And this is my JSX with the images.

```
        <ImageList cols={1}>
          {imageURIs.map((imageURI) => (
            <ImageListItem key={imageURI}>
              <img
                src={`${imageURI}`}
                srcSet={`${imageURI}`}
                loading="lazy"
                // loading="eager"  default
              />
            </ImageListItem>
          ))}
        </ImageList>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make `imageURIs` as an array of object instead of array and a assign a number prop as your reference to order it by when you render it.

`setImageURIs(prevImageUris => [...prevImageUris, {uri: e.data, number: prevImageUris.length + 1}])`

and use `sort` when rendering

```
{imageURIs.sort((a,b) => b.number - a.number).map((imageURI) => (
  <ImageListItem key={imageURI.uri}>
    <img
     src={`${imageURI.uri}`}
     srcSet={`${imageURI.uri}`}
     loading="lazy"
     // loading="eager"  default
     />
  </ImageListItem>
))}
```

Comment: I fear I might've miscommunicated. To clarify, I only want to display a single image at any given moment; specifically, I want to display only the most recent image URI. If I understand this correctly, I think this would display all, ordered by when they arrived, yes?

Comment: By latest image, yes. Since you have the data with number property, you will grab the last data(has highest num property value in imgUris array). So there's no need to map. And add imageUris as a dependency in your useEffect

Comment: I am confused. This will show multiple images, yes? I do not want multiple images shown. I want one shown. 

I think the sort is also unnecessary, yes? Because we can just append to an array.

Comment: Yes it shows multiple image. You use map in your code thats why it is confusing, why use map if you only render 1 item. Do you have a property or something to distinguish the recent image? if not then you need sort or much better store all the value and grab the last array. So it will be setImageURIs(prevImageURIS => [...prevImageURIS , e.data]) then in your render no need to map <ImageListItem>
    <img
     src={`${imageURIs.slice(-1)[0]}`}
     srcSet={`${imageURIs.slice(-1)[0]}`}
     loading="lazy"
     // loading="eager"  default
     />
  </ImageListItem>

Comment: I use map in my code because I intend (in the future) to render multiple items that will be sent from the server simultaneously.

Comment: To clarify, I don't need to store past values. I just need the current image URI and the next image URI, and then the ability to switch them once the next image URI's data has been loaded.